# Problem with calling the jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, xml, menu

I have the following jQuery function, I am trying to call `OnMenuClick` function by sending my `MenuId` as the parameter, but my `OnMenuClick` event is not giving the desired output, is their any alternate way to achieve this?

```
function CreateMenus(results) {
 for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  $("<div class='Menu'>" + results[i].Text + "</div>")
     .click({ MenuId: results[i].MenuId }, OnMenuClick)
     .appendTo("#accordionContainer");
 }
}
```

This is my `OnMenuClick` function

```
function OnMenuClick(event)
     {
    $("div[id ^= 'menuItemGroup']").slideUp(500);
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "MenuItems.asmx/GetMenuItems",
            data: '{"menuId":"' + event.data.MenuId + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(items) {
                $(event.target).children().remove();
                var html = "<div id='menuItemGroup" + event.data.MenuId + "' style='display:none'>";
                for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                    html += "<div class='MenuItem'> <a href='" + items[j].NavigateUrl + "'>"  + 
                    items[j].Text + "</a></div>";
                }
                html += "</div>";
                $(event.target).append(html);
                $("#menuItemGroup" + event.data.MenuId).slideDown(500);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
            }
        }
    )
}
```

This will be my sample XML output if the `MenuId` value `1` is passed to `OnClick`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <ArrayOfMenuItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <MenuItem>
      <MenuId>1</MenuId> 
      <MenuItemId>1</MenuItemId> 
      <Text>Books</Text> 
      <NavigateUrl>google.com</NavigateUrl> 
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>
      <MenuId>1</MenuId> 
      <MenuItemId>2</MenuItemId> 
      <Text>Cd</Text> 
      <NavigateUrl>yahoo.com</NavigateUrl> 
    </MenuItem>
  </ArrayOfMenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

it may not be the solution but you can try

first append the div to  the container and then do the binding

```
function CreateMenus(results) {
 for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  $("<div class='Menu'>" + results[i].Text + "</div>")         
     .appendTo("#accordionContainer")
     .click({ MenuId: results[i].MenuId }, OnMenuClick);
 }
}
```

HTH...